# How to install PHPUnit for CakePHP now that the PEAR method is no longer possible

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I tried to follow CakePHP 2.X [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html) to install PHPUnit 3.7.32 but the PEAR method is no longer valid ([see here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method)). What is the best way to install PHPUnit now?

Comment: Are you using composer for your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Composer

Use either [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org/), which is supported for quite some time now and has the PHPUnit dependency already added in the included `composer.json`

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.0/composer.json**

### .phar

or the PHPUnit `.phar` variant, which is [**supported since recently**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5248), all you need to do is to put the `phpunit.phar` file in the vendors folder (both `/vendors/` and `/app/Vendor/` will work).

- **https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/releases/tag/3.7.32**
- **https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/releases/download/3.7.32/phpunit.phar**

Comment: Upgrading Cakephp to 2.6.0 and putting the phpunit.phar in the vendors folder worked! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it's very difficult to find any information on this. We have an application using CakePHP 2.3 which relied on PEAR installation of PHPUnit which is no longer available, been trying to find out how I can use the PHAR version, looks like I need to update to CakePHP 2.6.